# R code to insert rows based on a column's value and increment it by 1

Tags: r

I have two columns in my data as shown below. I want to insert rows based on the value in Total column. Eg. For record1, the total value is 9. So, there should be 9 records for the code XS1.1 with Total starting from 1 till 9. Please find below the expected output for better clarity. I am just learning the basics of R. Could you please help me with the code?

```
Code        Total
XS1.1       9
W1.23       3
Kj1.9       2
```

**Output Expected:**

```
Code     Total
XS1.1    1
XS1.1    2
XS1.1    3
XS1.1    4
XS1.1    5
XS1.1    6
XS1.1    7
XS1.1    8
XS1.1    9
W1.23    1
W1.23    2
W1.23    3
Kj1.9    1
Kj1.9    2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(Total=1:Total), code]
```

Or base `R`:

```
with(df, data.frame(code=rep(code, Total), Total=sequence(Total)))
```

Comment: Didn't saw that you posted a similar version in base R.

Comment: no worries, and ... I guess I remind sequence since one of your former post ;)

Comment: Thanks Colonel. I tried the code library(data.table)
setDT(df.WRawQuart)[,.(Total=1:Total), code]. But its throwing this error. Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'code' not found Can you please help?

Comment: I tried your other suggestion as well. with(df.WRawQuart, data.frame(code=rep(code, Total), Total=sequence(Total))) It gives me this error Error in data.frame(code = rep(code, Total), Total = sequence(Total)) : 
  object 'code' not found Can you please help?

Comment: Code with a capital letter sorry, it should correspond to the name of your columns.

Comment: Thanks Colonel. I have changed it to Caps C in Code. I get this error now. setDT(df.WRawQuart)[,.(Total=1:Total), Code].. Error in 1:Total : NA/NaN argument

Comment: And I get this error for the below code. with(df.WRawQuart,data.frame(Code=rep(Code,Total),Total=sequence(Total))) Error in rep(Code, Total) : invalid 'times' argument

Comment: Hey i cant help like this. The example you posted did not reflect what you effectively have. You should update your post or ask a new question with a representative sample which does not work.

Comment: The example I listed above is exactly same as what I am working on now. Its ok if you cant help. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First make that data frame you expect beforehand, after that make your desired data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame("Code"=c("XS1.1","W1.23","Kj1.9"),"Total"=c(9,3,2))
dat2 <- data.frame("Code"=rep(dat[,1],dat[,2]),"Total"=c(seq(1:dat[1,2]),seq(1:dat[2,2]),seq(1:dat[3,2])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Code) %>%
  complete(Total = full_seq(1:Total, 1))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [14 x 2]
#Groups: Code [3]
# 
#     Code Total
#   <fctr> <dbl>
#1   Kj1.9     1
#2   Kj1.9     2
#3   W1.23     1
#4   W1.23     2
#5   W1.23     3
#6   XS1.1     1
#7   XS1.1     2
#8   XS1.1     3
#9   XS1.1     4
#10  XS1.1     5
#11  XS1.1     6
#12  XS1.1     7
#13  XS1.1     8
#14  XS1.1     9
```

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I am trying all your solutions one by one. @Steven, I am trying to use your code and I have got an error. Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  unknown variable to group by : Code.. Can you please help me fix the error? I am sorry if did something like a dumb. Here is my code. library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(mi)
df.WPnRawQuarter %>%
group_by(Code) %>%
Complete(Total = full_seq(1:Total, 1))

Comment: It works just fine for the example you provided. Maybe post a `dput(head(df.WPnRawQuarter))` ? Also, it seems you used `Complete` instead of `complete` ?

Comment: Yes, I have replaced Complete with complete. It gives me this error now. Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘complete’ for signature ‘"grouped_df", "missing"’. Here is what you have asked for.. structure(list(Code = c("C01", "M.1", "R", "N", "R2", 
"C1"), Total = c(1, 9, 9, 9, 10, 9)), .Names = c("Code", "Total"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame").

Comment: It works just fine on my end using your `dput`. Maybe restart `R` and reload packages. Also, make sure you have the latest version of the packages.

Comment: Sure. Thank you. I will do that. I think tidyr has the complete function. I have already installed it. Let me restart and see what happens.